# C++: template method in the base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have my base class:

```
class UnitTestThread : public testing::Test
{
    public:
        /// purgeQueue()
        template <typename T> void purgeQueue(const ___handle queue, T &data) const;
};
```

And my inheritance class:

```
class HmiTest : public UnitTestThread
{
    public:         
        // Sets up the test fixture.
        virtual void SetUp();
        // ...
}

void HmiTest::SetUp()
{
    // By default , purge all the queues
    CONTROL_ACTION_PARAM controlAction;
    purgeQueue(ApplicationContext.queueControlActionsToThermostat, controlAction);
}
```

And I have a link error:

```
HmiTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall UnitTestThread::purgeQueue<struct CONTROL_ACTION_PARAM>(void * const,struct CONTROL_ACTION_PARAM &)const " (??$purgeQueue@UCONTROL_ACTION_PARAM@@@UnitTestThread@@QBEXQAXAAUCONTROL_ACTION_PARAM@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall HmiTest::SetUp(void)" (?SetUp@HmiTest@@UAEXXZ)
```

I don't understand why ... :-S

Thank you so much for your help guys !

Comment: Where is `purgeQueue` defined?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: @Anthony You need to accept an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have declared the method, but you've not implemented it. Or if you have, it's in a cpp file, which is no good (needs to be in a header for a template method, or use explicit template instantiation).

You need to implement the method after the class definition:

```
class UnitTestThread : public testing::Test
{
    public:
        /// purgeQueue()
        template <typename T>
        void purgeQueue(const ___handle queue, T &data) const;
};

template <typename T>
void UnitTestThread::purgeQueue(const ___handle queue, T &data) const
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: I have implemented in my UnitTestThread.cpp file

/// purgeQueue()
template <typename T> void UnitTestThread::purgeQueue(const ___handle queue, T &data) const
{
    // ...
}

Comment: @Anthony as he said, your template needs to be defined in the the header file, not the .cpp file.

Comment: Or use explicit template instantiation if you know exactly which types you'll be working with.

Answer (score 2):

Template implementation should be included in the header (.h) file